# How to detect gender for a specific object id?

Tags: python, opencv, logic, openvino

I'm working with an OpenVino python code for Age and Gender Detection. The code runs on each frame.
I have a .py file for centroid tracking and allocating objectID. This is used to track the count of the total number of people appearing during any given session.

But now, I am trying to create a GUI for the above code, where it shows the total male and total female count. As and when a person comes (registeration of objectID takes place in my code) and goes (deregistration of objectID), I also want it to increment the appropriate gender count.

This is a snippet of my code:

```
while has_frame:
        rects=[]
        frame1 = np.array(frame, dtype='uint8')
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
                    frame1,
                    scaleFactor=1.2,
                    minNeighbors=5,     
                    minSize=(20, 20)
                )
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                cv.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
                rects.append((x,y,(x+w),(y+h)))
                x = int(x)
                y = int(y)
                w = int(w)
                h = int(h)

                if run_age_gender:
                    cropped_image = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                    if cropped_image.size > 0:
                        age_inference.infer(cropped_image)
                        age, gender = age_inference.get_age_gender_data() #retreives the age and gender
                        age_gender_text = '{} - {}'.format(age , gender)
                        cv.putText(frame, age_gender_text, org=((x+w), (y+10)), fontFace=cv.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                                   fontScale=1, color=(0, 64, 255), thickness=1, lineType=cv.LINE_AA)
        
        objects,intervals = ct.update(rects) #ct.update references my "centroidtracking.py" file to get objectID and time interval for each objectID (time spent by a given person in front of camera)

        for (objectID, centroid) in objects.items():
                text = "ID {}".format(objectID)
                cv.putText(frame, text, (centroid[0] - 10, centroid[1] - 10),
                    cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv.circle(frame, (centroid[0], centroid[1]), 4, (0, 255, 0), -1)

        for (objectID, time) in intervals.items():
                totaltime+=time
                totalppl+=1

        text = ("%0.2f" %(totaltime))
        self.ui.timetextbox.setPlainText(text)
        text2 = ("%d" %(totalppl))
        self.ui.ppltextbox.setPlainText(text2)

        if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                     break

        has_frame, frame = source.read()
        frame_id += 1
```

This is just a snippet of my while loop where both age & gender and object ID tracking takes place.

As of now if I try to count the male/female it increases the count for each frame and is independent of the person being detected.

If there are any suggestions for me to combine the two so that my age and gender detection takes place for a particular ID (person) instead of just running on each frame and detecting the gender on each frame?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you refer to People Counter Solution, available at
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/topics/iot/reference-implementations/people-counter-system.html

Information on implementing the counter is available at lines 91-110 of the main.py file.
https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/people-counter-python/blob/master/main.py#L91